# Replace numeric(0) with NAs in all lists in a column of lists in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, na

I have a column in a dataframe that stores lists. Here is an example below:

```
           col
1   9
2   8, 8, 8, 5
3   1, 8, 10, 4
4   3, 6, 1, 6
5   9, 9, 10, 4
6   8, 8, 9, 2
7   6, 10, 4, 7
8   6, 1, 5, 9
9   4, 7, 5, 10
10  7, 9, 2, 5
```

This is the code I used to generate the above example:

```
set.seed(123)
example <- data.frame(matrix(NA_real_, nrow=10, ncol=1))
colnames(example) <- "col"
for(y in 1:10) {
  example$col[y] <- list(c(c(sample(1:10,1)),c(sample(1:10,1)),c(sample(1:10,1)),c(sample(1:10,1))))
}

example$col[1] <- list(c(9))
```

I want to remove all occurrences of the number 9 from all of these lists, in this column of my data frame, to get something like this:

```
           col
1   NA
2   8, 8, 8, 5
3   1, 8, 10, 4
4   3, 6, 1, 6
5   10, 4
6   8, 8, 2
7   6, 10, 4, 7
8   6, 1, 5
9   4, 7, 5, 10
10  7, 2, 5
```

instead of this, which I'm currently getting with `example$col <- lapply(example$col, function(x){ x[x != 9] })`

```
           col
1   numeric(0)
2   8, 8, 8, 5
3   1, 8, 10, 4
4   3, 6, 1, 6
5   10, 4
6   8, 8, 2
7   6, 10, 4, 7
8   6, 1, 5
9   4, 7, 5, 10
10  7, 2, 5
```

How can I replace the `numeric(0)` with `NA_real_` and still be able to remove all the 9s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `lapply` statement like so

```
lapply(example$col, function(x){ y <- x[x != 9]; if(length(y) < 1) { y <- NA }; y })
```

As own function - makes it easier to modify in the future

```
remove_num <- function(vec, num) {
   x <- vec[vec != num]
   if (length(x) < 1) { x <- NA }
   x
}

lapply(example$col, remove_num, 9)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do both, remove the 9s *and* change single 9s to `NA_real_`, in one step with an `if` statement.

```
example$col <- lapply(example$col, function(x) {
    if(length(x) == 1L && x == 9) NA_real_ else x[x != 9]
})

example
#             col
# 1            NA
# 2      10, 1, 6
# 3   6, 5, 10, 5
# 4       7, 6, 2
# 5   3, 1, 4, 10
# 6      7, 7, 10
# 7    7, 8, 6, 6
# 8  3, 2, 10, 10
# 9    7, 8, 1, 5
# 10   8, 3, 4, 3
```